# Using readlines in python? First time

Tags: python, readlines

I have a text file with columns of data and I need to turn these columns into individual lists or arrays.
This is what I have so far

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
temp = []
for row in f.readlines():
    Data = row.split()
    temp.append(float(Data[0]))
```

When I run this I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Snippet of the data below:

```
16  0.2000  
17  0.3000  
18  0.4000  
20  0.5000  
21  0.6000  
22  0.7000
24  0.8000  
25  0.9000
26  1.000
```

I need the first column, if possible to look like this:
Data = [16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26]

Comment: [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) is your friend.

Comment: ...shouldn't this be `for row in f.readlines():` or more simply `for row in f`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting an empty list `Data=[]` if you read an empty row. You try to get the first element from the list using `Data[0]`,but because it's an empty list it doesn't have an element at position 0, so you get an `IndexError`.

```
Data=''.split()

Data[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-686-0792b03cbbdf> in <module>()
----> 1 Data[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This will print out the `Data` if `IndexError` occours - you can see yourself that it prints an empty list:

```
f=open('file','r')
temp = []
for row in f.readlines():
    Data = row.split()
    try:
        temp.append(float(Data[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print Data
```

You can use the `with` statement to open the file, that automatically closes the file after being processed. Also you can loop over the file itself, without using `readlines()`.

```
with open(file,'r') as f:        
     for row in f:
         Data = row.split()
         try:
            print Data[0]
         except IndexError:
            print 'You have an empty row'
```

EDIT: You are better of using the csv module:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    print [row[0] for row in reader if len(row)]
>>> 
['16', '17', '18', '20', '21', '22', '24', '25', '26']
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback and suggestions. Is there a way that I can then get the Data into a list form like this: Data = [0, 1, etc]?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the data into a list because I need to then use it to perform a linear interpolation. If I use the last method you suggested, (using 'with') will that give me a list that I can then use later in my interpolation?

The 0,1, etc were just examples of the data values being imported

Comment: if you want to use interpolation take a look at the pandas library (it can import the data dirctly from csv), here's an interpolation example using pandas as an answer to a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982792/interpolate-number-sequence/12983037#12983037

Comment: Ok just one more question, will this work if I want to do the same for other columns from the data?

Comment: yes it will. just change row[0] to row[1], if you have rows that have the first value and not the second you may need to add if len(row)>1 to avoid index error.

Comment: I tried the code and rather than giving me the values just from the first column its giving me the values from all columns?

Comment: is the data still separated by a space? It looks like a delimeter issue.

Comment: Do you mean after I've run it? If so, then no its not

Comment: No in the file.  delimiter='' breaks the rows by whitspace, if it is something else that separates the values, it wont work.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I just checked and there is no spaces. I will put spaces and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

use with for filehandlers.

```
with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # code.
```

you index error comes from trying to access `Data` at the `[0]` location.
which simply means your line was empty.

you should run a quick check before parsing the line...

```
if len(Data):
    #code
else:
    #empty line?
```

Comment: In Python, it is better to write `if len(Data):` and not `if len(Data) > 0:`.

Comment: @ Burhan Khalid -- cant you then just do if Data:?

Comment: @root no, because an empty list still exists. `>>> a=[]` `>>> print a` `[]`

Comment: @  Inbar Rose -- >>> if a:
...     print 'foo'
... else: print 'bar'
... 
bar

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
temp = []
for row in f.readlines():
    items = row.split(',')
    temp.append(unicode(items[0]))
```

I hope that it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cal(num_list):
    x = 1;
    z = 0;
    while True:
        list1 = list(str(x))
        list2 = [int(a) for a in list1]

        for i in range(len(list2)):
            for j in range(10):
                if(list2.count(j) > num_list[list2[i]]):
                    z = 1;
                    break;
        if(z == 1):   
            save(x);
            break;      
        x = x + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#matrix A to B
def show():
    global string_final,list_2,tot
    index=matrix_1.index(num)  # finding index of num

    length=n
    j=(index)%length # the column positon
    i=index/length # the row position

    list_1=[]
    for a in range(length):
        lis=[]
        for b in range(length):

            lis.append(matrix_1.pop(0)) #pop the first element and append the list

        list_1.append(lis)

    tot=0
    list_2=[]

    for a in range(i+1):
        for b in range(j+1):
            tot=tot+list_1[a][b] # add the numbers
            list_2.append(list_1[a][b]) #append to list
            if(b!=length):
                list_2.append(" ")  #append space
        list_2.append("\n")
    string_final="".join([str(a) for a in list_2])  #list to string


    print "matrix B\n",string_final,"\nx: ",str(num),"\nn: ",str(n)+"\ntotal: "+str(tot) # print the result
```

Comment: #mat A to b
def saveFile():
    file=open("matrix2.txt","w")
    file.write("matrixB\n"+string_final+"\nx: "+str(num)+"\nn: "+str(n)+"\ntotal: "+str(tot))
    file.close();
    

x=1
while x==1:
    getInput()
    if(n<=0 or n>=20): #check for the n
        print "enter correct n"
        break

    if(len(matrix_1)!=n*n or len(set(matrix_1))!=len(matrix_1)): # check the input is ok or not
        print "wrong input"
        break
    if(set([99>a>9 for a in matrix_1])!={True}):# check the value of n
        print "enter suitable number"
        break
    show()
    saveFile()
    x=x+1;

Comment: Comments destroy code formatting, especially in whitespace-significant languages. Please [edit] your answer to include the additional code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#matrix add zero
def get():
    global b_no
    num_list=[];
    file=open("matrix.txt","r");
    for i in file:
        b_no=0
        if(len(i.split())==1): #check length is 1 or not
            n=int(i)#string to int
        else:
            temp=i.split();
            if(len(temp)!=n):
                b_no+=1
                break
            temp=[0]+[int(a) for a in temp]+[0] #add zero at first and last
            num_list.append(temp);

    zero_list=[]

    for i in range(n+2):
        zero_list.append(0)         #append zero
    num_list.insert(0,zero_list)
    num_list.insert(n+1,zero_list)
    return num_list,n;
```

Comment: #mat Add zero# def cal():   
    list1=[];
    for row in range(1,n+1):
        for col in range(1,n+1):
            tot=0;
            count=0;
            for m in range(-1,2):
                for p in range(-1,2):
                    if(num_list[row+m][col+p]==0):  
                        count=count+1;
                    tot=tot+num_list[row+m][col+p];                    
            if(count!=0):
                tot=tot/(9-count);
            else:
                tot=tot/9
            list1.append(str(tot)+" ");
        list1.append("\n");

    print "".join([str(a) for a in list1])

Comment: x=1;
while x==1:
    num_list,n=get();
    if(n>20 or n<3):
        print "n should between 3 and 20"
        break
    if(b_no!=0):
        print "enter correctly"
        break

    cal()
    x=x+1;

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using Data[0] or row[0], instead, I would use ''.join(Data) or ''.join(row) to avoid empty list (list index out of range error).