# Retrieve source of web pages by providing file which contains multiple URLs

Tags: python, url, urllib

I want to download source of webpages by providing a file which contains a list of their URLs.
For example, I have a file which has following URLs

```
http://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb09-19.html
http://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb09-20.html
```

Can I do it using `urllib` because I want to use python modules not the unix commands (like wget)?

I want read this file and give each URL as input to urlopen or urlretrieve, can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Are you having a specific problem doing this? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to do that,not tried anything...

Comment: @Wayne Werner Can u give brief description about that...?

Comment: @Kummi_10 `man wget` should get you started...

Comment: Can i do it using urllib because I want to use python modules not the unix commands(like wget)?

Comment: `f=open('urllist','r')
for url in f.readlines():
    website = urllib2.urlopen(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break down the issue as best as you can. You've got a text file with each URL listed on its own line. You know that Python's got great support for reading line by line, thanks to `open()`, and you're probably familiar with [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), depending on your preference.

So all you need to do is:

1. [Open the file](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)
2. [Read line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724964/541208)
3. Use the line as an URL string
4. Send a request to the URL using [urllib](http://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls) or [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)
5. Capture the output and parse it/save it

And you're done!

Comment: Can show me how to Use the line as an URL string...?

Comment: @Kummi_10 You've got the line read into Python as a string, you then need to pass that string variable to the urllib/requests methods responsible for that.  In the answer listed in `2.`, you're able to see how he reads each line and calls it 'row'. If you call yours 'url' and do `requests.get(url)`, you should be in a good place to work out the rest.